# is AMD RS880M a dual core processor?

Tags: cpu

Is type AMD RS880M a dual core processor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [RS880M is not a processor at all (it is a chipset)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_800_chipset_series).

Comment: can you provide a source?

Comment: @dsg: Huh? Already did.

Comment: Sorry, the link was not showing up. I see it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's no processor, rather a chipset, but it is made for dual core CPUs [(source)](http://www.pcper.com/article.php?aid=778&type=expert)